# What causes the infinite redirect loop when I login to Gmail? How do I fix it?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, account-management, login

Of course I can't reproduce it now! However, about 20% of the time when I try to login to my Gmail account (because my wife is logged into hers), it gets stuck in an infinite redirect loop. I always end up surfing around to different Google sites for a while, and then eventually it fixes itself.

Anyone know how to fix this? What causes it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A couple things to try:

- Clear your cookies (if a duration is allowed, I'd try "everything")
- Clear your cache (if a duration is allowed, I'd try "everything")
- Make sure your system time is correct.
- If none of that works, try logging in with labs disabled:  http://mail.google.com/mail/?labs=0

Comment: FWIW I just remedied the infinite loop problem on iPad iOS 5 safari by clearing browsing history only.

Comment: doesn't work for me.. :(

Comment: Just clearing cookies on Chrome worked

Comment: For me adding recovery email and recovery phone solves the problem https://myaccount.google.com/

Answer (score 4):

I found that it was the Smart Labels feature available in Labs that caused the infinite redirect loop. After using http://mail.google.com/mail/?labs=0 to get into my mail, I disabled that lab feature. After that, I could access email again normally. It's a shame this answer (specifically to use the `labs=0` URL) isn't listed anywhere in the Google Apps help site.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. This happens for all google apps, and not just gmail.

Answer (score 1):

I started experiencing the infinite loop upon login after I added `https://mail.google.com` to my list of trusted sites in IE11 (*Tools → Internet Options → Security → Trusted Sites → Sites → Add*)

Once I removed `https://mail.google.com` from my trusted sites list, the issue cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like clearing the cookies should help it, however **that would be annoying to do every time you want to login to your Gmail account.**

I would therefore suggest that you either ask your wife to use the **private browsing/incognito mode of your browser**, or that you create a **separate browser profile**  for each of you (with Chrome, you can use ChromeDeck: http://lifehacker.com/5549178/chromedeck-creates-and-manages-multiple-chrome-profiles).

Alternatively, if you are happy to use a **desktop client, such as Thunderbird**, that should also solve your issues, albeit indirectly.

Comment: I have multiple accounts that I sign in and out of.  The redirect loop is not normal.  Just to clarify, I was not saying clearing data needed to be done every time, just once to get out of the corrupted state.

Comment: You can avoid signing in and out by using the [multiple sign-in](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=28776) feature

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable third-party cookies to make mine work. After cleaning everything out and logging in, the cookies I had were:
google-analytics.com
googleusercontent.com
gstatic.com
youtube.com

So, that's what google registers you with upon log in.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: on desktop, switching between profiles works fine but on mobile either I always get to the first account page or get infinite redirects between two accounts.

The workaround that works for me: Switch on "PC version" option in settings (but then you get desktop view of your inbox, of course).

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by disabling the Hola extension in chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem on my Android phone when I log into 9 Gmail accounts. The last Gmail account X that I added always routes me to the first Gmail account Y. After reading this thread, I cleared all my cookies and then re-logged into X first. It worked! I then added most of the other Gmail accounts and all worked fine, but maybe it is because I now log into 7 Gmail accounts instead of 9. I didn't have the initial problem when I logged into 8 Gmail accounts, so maybe 8 is the maximum number of Gmail accounts you can log in on Android phones.

Comment: Questions (and answers) here should be concerned with the web interface. How logins work on Android has little to no bearing here.